How can I set any keyboard layout?
If I use S+space then I see three layout options: Estonian, French (AZERTY, AFNOR) and Greek. They work. Now, I want to add Russian but I find no option in XFCE to do that. If I go Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout then there are Estonian, Greek and Russian. On the panel, there is Estonian flag in the corner. Clicking it does nothing. Previously, it reacted and only the flag changed not the keyboard layout.
